# is there an easy way to make a parent components links override a child components links in react components?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-component

A quick question, is there a way for a person to set up a link or a nav link in a parent component so that it overrides links in child components automatically  in react? I have a parent component that is made up of several child components, and I would like one section of it to ignore the child links and do something else ( reroute to a different, totally new component.)I guess i can do this by passing some kind of flag to the underlying components via props but just wondering if there is a shortcut.

This would make my life a lot easier... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind it seems to work v easily by simply adding the  component from react-router-dom, thanks for looking